# Selenium ChromeDriver gives an errors after one hour of running

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots

I'm new with selenium and I try to build a bot to do some logic on a specific website. I use C# .NET 4.6, Chrome v.108 and latest Selenium and chrome driver from Nuget. The flow itself can be less then a few seconds, and if it's failed, I want it to try again, until it will accomplish it.

Potentially, it can runs a lot of hours (or even a day or two) until it will success. However, after an hour or two, it start to throw A LOT exceptions, the most common is these three:

```
disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer)
  (Session info: headless chrome=108.0.5359.125)*

An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL ___localhostURL___ The exception message was: An error occurred while sending the request.

The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL ___localhostURL___ timed out after 60 seconds.
```

I tried to run my bot, both on my machine and on a docker as well, and I got the same errors after a while.

I search these errors over the net and tried some solutions (most of them was to add some arguments to the ChromeOptions) but actually they didn't help me so much and I still get these errors.

This is my code:

```
private void Func()
{
    var status = Status.Failed;
    ChromeDriver driver = null;

    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--headless");
    options.AddArgument("--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166'");
    options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(path/to/chromedrive.exe, options);
    //driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(dockerUrl), options);

    do
    {
        try
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(PageUrl);
            status = Func2(driver);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteException(ex);
        }
    } while (status == Status.Failed);

    driver?.Quit();
}
```

- User agent argument is because the specific website block headless browser and this is how I found how to bypass this block.
- All other arguments is a solutions I found to fix the problems above which didn't help so much.
- I know I can use `driver.Navigate().Refresh();` instead of `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(PageUrl);` every iteration, but with Refresh() it doesn't do what I want since it refresh the current page and not the main one.
- Both with `RemoteWebDriver` (will run the bot on a docker) and `ChromeDriver` I get the same errors.
- I tried without path to chromedriver.exe (actually I didn't know I need this one at all since it works the same without it as well) but with or without path to chromedriver.exe it still get these errors.
- These errors raise on the `GoToUrl` line

Any insights or tips what to change or what to check to fix my problems? 
Thanks

Comment: You might just need to quit the driver, dispose of it, and recreate it when this starts happening. I wonder if the browser is crashing?

Comment: When I test it firstly without headless argument, the browser was display and didn't crash. In this flow the browser is headless so I not see it with my own eyes, but the process itself still exists so I don't think it crash. 

so in my catch block I need to search for those three exceptions and if it one of them, call to Quit() and then recreate it in the try block?

Comment: Sometimes you just need to try something repeatedly. Catch the exception thrown from `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(...)`, and attempt to call that method again after a small timeout. Sometimes you just need to kill the browser and start over. There is an element of experimentation here.

Comment: Do I need to set the driver to null before recreate it or it doesn't matter?
means
`driver.Quit();
driver.Dispose();
driver = null;
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverPath, options);
`

Comment: You shouldn't need to set it to null.

Comment: Thanks. After more than 12 hours of running, those errors happend only 5 times but the bot is keep running (before that - once an error raised it failed to continue, and just throw again and again and again).

Comment: @GregBurghardt, unfortunately, after a 24 hours of running it was crash (totaly) with "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable" exception and this try of create a new ChromeDriver has failed

Comment: The next thing to do is retry the creation of ChromeDriver.

Comment: this isn't what you told to do from the first place? quit it, dispose it and re-create it. Now I see I wasn't clear enough. this crash come from the catch block itself, meaning it throws exception when I try to recreate ChromeDriver, and since the catch block hasn't try-catch inside it, so all my app was crash since no another catch block were exists.

Comment: No, I understand it is throwing in the catch block. :) Sometimes you just need to try, and try again... and maybe even a third or fourth time, or some number of times until you give up.

Comment: BTW, this can be a *really* hard problem to solve. If you get too much instability, you might consider if Selenium is really the right tool for the job.

Comment: Wierd, It seems that even when it has been recreate, for some reason it's not really continue. According to my exception logs, in the last 7 hours it crash after 1 hour of running (after 768 iterations) and the next log was written after 3 hours but for some reason it still on the iteration #768 (it keeps count since the counter is a global one). I don't know how it possible and why my while loop isn't run for almost 3 hours. REALLY strange and I don't know what is change, for example, from my last long running.

Comment: Any other recommend tool instead Selenium for C#? I am not familiar with those tools at all. My purpose with this app is to try to fill a form, pick some options from a dropdowns, wait for elements, execute native javascript , and some other things, and at the end I want to submit a meeting if one is available (according to datepicker) (this is why I have the loop). in my flow I also solving two recaptchas. any recommendation for something can do that instead of selenium?

Comment: Is there a REST or other web API you can use?

Comment: Few days ago I thought to leave automation, and try to use REST since I just need to do some "login" (userId + DOB), then, I believe, I get some sessionId which I will use it next steps, then another call to check if there are available meetings (the response for this request is a JSON represent a list of { date: x, time: y, id: guid }) and submit one of this avalilable by its uniqueidentifier and my id. So I if will know how to simulate these requests I don't need browsers, only http requests. unfortunally it doesn't work well and too complicated (although sound simple) so I back to Selenium

Comment: @GregBurghardt I add a "WriteToLog" function for debugging purposes. Every 10 min (check inside my while loop) it writes to a text file so I will know it still in progress. After few hours of running and writing every 10 min. It stops. Without exception. So it looks like the exceptions are not the issue.  My whole func run parallel with three differrent  tasks. All of them writing to log and all of them stop working on the same time even though they are different instances and no common reasources. Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it all was because Sleep-mode on my laptop. 
 When I change it to "Never" it seems like it fixed and run more then 24 hours without any issues.